# How to change each columns item font size in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I want to change each columns font size. I am using listview with Gridview. I want the result something like this:

[image]

Here is my XML Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" Margin="0,0,-5,-5" FontSize="20">
     <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding c1}" />
               <GridViewColumn Header="Column2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding c2}" Width="780"/>
               <GridViewColumn Header="Column3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding c3}" Width="460"/>
           </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**C#:**

```
this.listView1.Items.Add(new MyItem { c1= "This is Column 1 Row 1 Text", c2="This is Column 2 Row 1 Text", c3= "This is Column 3 Row 1 Text" });


class MyItem
{

    public string c1{ get; set; }

    public string c2{ get; set; }

    public string c3{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use the [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx) instead of `DisplayMemberBinding` to have full customization options.

---

For the first column something like:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Column1">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding c1}" FontSize="15px"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: It says CellTemplate is not Recognized

Comment: The [`GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) Property page on MSDN would disagree with you.

Comment: @UzairAli: You did nest it in the `GridViewColumn`, right?

Comment: yes where I need to change or add cell template `<GridView>  <GridViewColumn Header="Column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding c1}" />`

Comment: @UzairAli: I edited my code before the previous comment, it appears you did not understand what i meant, have a look at the code...